# Extracting a large number of fields for each document in a MongoDB aggregation query

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection. In it, each document has an item ID, a time field, and a large number of other fields. The item IDs are repeated. I want to extract all the data from the last document in this collection for each distinct item ID. One approach that works is the following:

```
db.items.aggregate({
    $sort: {time: -1}}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {item: '$item.id'},
        time: {$first: '$time'},
        anotherField: {$first: '$anotherField'},
        yetAnotherField: {$first: '$yetAnotherField'},
        ...
    }
})
```

...however, I would need to add an expression for each field in the document that I want to pull, which is quite clunky. Is there a query that accomplishes this as computationally efficiently (or better) as the above but more gracefully?

Comment: Your question says "last document" but your example code uses `$first`, so which is it? :)

Comment: @JohnnyHK, he says `{ "$sort": { "time": -1 } }`. So ordered to the "last" time when using `$first`. Presuming this is `$first` for every field except the grouping key. So the problem here is what exactly? That you don't want to type all that out?

Comment: @NeilLunn Yeah, that's probably it.

Comment: I aggree that `$$ROOT` is the simple way to handle this even if it does alter the document a little. But you can always code this as your application "should" really have some concept of an expected schema and it's all just then traversing and generating a data structure. You should almost never be "hand typing" queries like this.

Comment: Yes, @NeilLunn, the problem was that I didn't want to type all that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$$ROOT`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) to reference the entire doc in your `$group`.

So to get the most recent (i.e. last) doc for each group you can do:

```js
db.items.aggregate({
    $sort: {time: -1}}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {item: '$item.id'},
        lastDoc: {$first: '$$ROOT'}
    }
})
```

Comment: I had to upgrade to 2.6 but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!